# Value of Ajax generated select box not changing when called associated with  jquery auto complete 

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

The below code having a selectbox with id='theservice' and a text field with id ='servicename'.This code autocompletes the servicename text field by checking which service is active in the service selectbox.But unfortunately the source string remains the same eventhought the selectbox is changed.

```
$( "#servicename" ).autocomplete({

        source: "index.php?key="+($('#theservice').find('option:selected').val()),
        minLength: 2,
    });
```

Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the `.autocomplete( "option" , optionName , [value] )` method

$( "#servicename" ).autocomplete({

```
        source: "index.php?key="+($('#theservice').find('option:selected').val()),
        minLength: 2,
            search: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#servicename" ).autocomplete( "option" ,'source' ,'index.php?key="+($('#theservice').find('option:selected').val()));}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a `delegation` issue.

**Autocomplete propagation example added**

```
//build the autocomplete function, sans source
$('#servicename').autocomplete({
  minLength: 2
});

var theArray = [];
$('body').on('change', 'select', function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?key='+$(this).val(),
    dataType: 'json/jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      //i don't know what the array you return looks like, but autocomplete expets a key:value relationship
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        theArray.push({label: value, value: key});
      });
      //a custom function to pass the array into
      startAutoComplete(theArray);
    }
  });
});

function startAutoComplete(array){
  $('#servicename').autocomplete('option', 'source', array);
}
```

Using the above code, we instantiate the autocomplete instance, we only identify the parameters we need **excluding** the source.

We then define an empty array that we can push the data returned from our ajax request into.

In our select function, we pass the value over to the server to be parsed. I don't know if you are expecting JSON/JSONP formatting, so you'll have to change that yourself.

In the `success:function(data)` we're getting back the request from the server, it would be best if the response was `json_encode`'ed. Also, when we push the values into the array, it's best to use a `key -> value` relationship. Autocomplete allows for a `label` and a `value` to be accessed like `function(event, ui){ //do stuff with ui.item.label / ui.item.value}`'

We declare an uninitialized function outside of the scope of `document.ready`, and pass the array into the function. Within this function, we change the source of the autocomplete.

Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: this was ok for the select , but the problem here is with the auto complete url `$( "#servicename" ).autocomplete({

        source: "index.php?key="+($('#theservice').find('option:selected').val()),
        minLength: 2,
    });`

Comment: I don't think that jQuery UI Autocomplete accepts a call to a file as a source, you would need to build the array `outside of the autocomplete` and pass it in as a variable. see example above.

Comment: jQuery UI Autocomplete has an option to call files to work with remote data.ie portion works good.